# Angular App not compiling when Component is Deleted

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

When I delete a component, (say nav-bar.component.ts and it's folder), The app fails to compile. I have removed the declaration from app.module.ts. The error that is being thrown says it has to do with "include.module.ts," which has nothing to do with nav-bar.component.ts.

Here is the CLI output:

```
C:\Users\Daniel\dev-projects\vile>ng serve
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Date: 2017-12-04T17:02:37.587Z
Hash: d00b13e972db5b32e6b8
Time: 2988ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 5.83 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 1.06 kB {vendor} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 323 bytes {inline} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 56.5 kB {inline} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 338 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module C:/Users/Daniel/dev-projects/vile/node_modules/@angular/material/toolbar/typings/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol IncludeModule in C:/Users/Daniel/dev-projects/vile/src/app/include/include.module.ts, resolving symbol IncludeModule in C:/Users/Daniel/dev-projects/vile/src/app/include/include.module.ts
    at Error (native)
    at syntaxError (C:\Users\Daniel\dev-projects\vile\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
    at simplifyInContext (C:\Users\Daniel\dev-projects\vile\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24979:23)
    at StaticReflector.simplify (C:\Users\Daniel\dev-projects\vile\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24991:13)
    at StaticReflector.annotations (C:\Users\Daniel\dev-projects\vile\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24418:41)
    at _getNgModuleMetadata (C:\Users\Daniel\dev-projects\vile\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:138:31)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (C:\Users\Daniel\dev-projects\vile\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:109:26)
    at C:\Users\Daniel\dev-projects\vile\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:129:27
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (C:\Users\Daniel\dev-projects\vile\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:128:10)
    at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (C:\Users\Daniel\dev-projects\vile\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (C:\Users\Daniel\dev-projects\vile\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:91:39)
    at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (C:\Users\Daniel\dev-projects\vile\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:207:44)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (C:\Users\Daniel\dev-projects\vile\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:443:24)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: You have removed files and folders for that component but you may have not removed its path in some other file. Check If there is one. And also check for the version of the file 'index.d.ts', use v3 instead of v4. In short keep the same version at both the places.

Comment: Error says that you use v4 instead of v3 of @angular/material. Change the version to v3 and run npm install

Answer (score 3):

running `ng serve` command did not work for me. However the reason why i'm getting this error is because not saving the module.ts file. Make sure you save all the files. Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. I had imported a module (MatToolbarModule from '@angular/material/toolbar') in include.module.ts (my module to import other modules) that was exported to nav-bar.module.ts. For some reason, even though there should have been no problem with include.module.ts exporting MatToolbarModule, it failed to compile. MY simple fix: remove the import statement for MatToolbarModule and put it back again.

Comment: If your are using angular-cli, when a file is added/removed some times you must stop the "ng server" and re-run again

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by stopping the application with ctrl+c and re-running "ng serve" command.